# Code equivalent for storyboard UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, uibutton, uistoryboard

I have a few custom buttons set up on the storyboard that I was trying to recreate in code, but somehow I'm not getting the position right in spite of using the same parameters in my CGRectMake function. Another issue is that the autoresizing mask is not working in code in the sense that I have the left, bottom and right strut highlighted so the buttons hold position in both 3.5" and 4" screen size, however my buttons created through code don't do this. I'm posting the XML from my storyboard and then my code to show what exactly I mean. Before the code,a bit of context into what I'm trying to do. I have these custom buttons across multiple controllers/views in my project set up through storyboard.. I"m trying to create a separate controller now with the buttons in the controller programmatically and then have my other controllers inherit from this so that in case I need to make modifications, these will just have to be done once.

Here's my code:

This is the XML From the storyboard:

```
<button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" id="iz0-cT-TPO">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="357" width="106" height="60"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="15"/>
                            <state key="normal" image="Anotpressed.png">
                                <color key="titleColor" red="0.19607843459999999" green="0.30980393290000002" blue="0.52156865600000002" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <color key="titleShadowColor" white="0.5" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>
                            <state key="highlighted" image="Apressed.png">
                                <color key="titleColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            </state>

                        </button>
```

My equivalent code in my view controller is:

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIButton *AButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [AButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 357, 106, 60)];
    [AButton setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [AButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Anotpressed"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [AButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Apressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [AButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:AButton];
}
```

At the moment what I'm doing is leaving the storyboard buttons in place and then inheriting from the view controller with the programmatic buttons in order to see if they are the same and I find that my programmatic buttons are much higher than the storyboard buttons even though they have the same co-ordinates etc.

I apologize for how verbose this question is, but I wanted to provide a complete picture of what I'm trying to achieve. First of all, how to recreate the same button programmatically and secondly is this (inheritance/subclassing) the correct way to recreate these buttons all across my project?

Comment: TL|DR but maybe because you are creating the button on viewDidAppear: instead of doing it on viewDidLoad you are skipping some orientation events or something like that. When programmatically creating objects create them at viewDidLoad and only use viewDidAppear: to set states that need to be like that every time the view appears in the screen. In this case you are going to create a new button every time you dismiss a fullscreen modal view controller from that view controller.

Comment: You can do that also in viewDidLoad if that state is never changed. If it's indeed changed while the user interacts with the view and you want that state to be reset the next time the view does show up then do it on viewDidAppear:. Think about that this way: your view can be kept in memory even when the user changes tabs in a tab view controller instead of being created every time. So there are two events here: creation and show. ViewDidLoad is for when the view is created and viewDidAppear: for when the view is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `flexibleMinY` states that the views in the storyboard can be repositioned if the parent view resizes. What probably happens is that the view is loaded at a certain size, but is resized to accommodate the available screen space. For example if the storyboard is designed for the iPhone 4 screen size, but is displayed on the new iPhone 5 screen resolution.

Because you add your buttons in `viewDidAppear`, the resizing already happened. The buttons have moved down a little and are not in the original position anymore.

You can try adding your buttons in `viewDidLoad`, which is probably being called before displaying and resizing the original view. Also add the same `autoresizingMask` to your buttons.

Or make sure the y position of your original buttons is fixed instead of flexible.

Comment: I added the buttons in viewDidLoad, nothing really changed. How do I do the flexibleMinY programatically and also how is this being done through storyboards as in what have I clicked/enabled in the storyboard on that is causing this?

Comment: set the `autoresizingMask` on your programatically created buttons to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`. Or disable the flexible top margin in Interface Building in the `Size inspector` for the existing buttons.

Comment: If you noticed the code, that is what I'm doing already. I already have UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin with the exact same co-ordinates and widths and heights as the buttons on the storyboard. And yet there is a massive different in the positioning of the buttons when they should be in the same position. When you compare my XML to my Objective C code is there anything else that I may be missing out?

Comment: Just to be sure, auto layout is disabled?

Comment: Yes it is, Another thing that I noticed is that unlike in storyboard my autoresizing masks don't seem to work when done through code. I learn this because I tested out on different sizes through the simulator and sometimes when I can see it on the 4" its not even visible on the 3.5" in spite of having the exact same configuration as the storyboard buttons. Another question, right now, I have the button set up in viewdidLoad for the class that creates them and then I have [super viewdidLoad] in the viewdidload method of the viewcontroller.m where I'm inheriting & trying to display these buttons

Comment: Another very curious thing that I've noticed is that values in the size inspector in storyboard do not match those in XML (I"m talking about button widths, heights and such)

Comment: You say that the autoresizing masks don't work by testing 3.5" and 4" screens. And what about when you change orientation? What is the behavior?

Comment: I'd suggest that you delete the button and create it again to see if they keep not matching.

Comment: I've got it all working now. Instead of using a fixed value for the height of my buttons, I just used a fixed difference from the bottom of the screen and this worked for me.